# Or operator '||' not working in firebase rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to change my firebase realtime database rules so that I can access it from both authenticated and unauthenticated users, I changed them to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth != null" ||"auth==null"
  }
}
```

But the or operator `||` is not working. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to quote the whole expression: `"a || b"`, in your case you can simply use `".write": true`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: what about space not sure but a guess!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This

```
{
    "rules:{
        ".read": "auth == null",
        ".write": "auth != null || auth==null"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, If you want to allow both users authenticated and non-authenticated , it means you want to allow all users to access database, then you can do this :

These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
read and write access to your database

`{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`